# How to format payload data to only contains data that corresponds with the specific section?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects for different sections. Each object contains name and value pair. Right now the same section with different name and value pair is getting displayed. How can I format the data so that the section is repeated only once and inside the section its corresponding name and value pair exists?

For example, this is the current format of the data:
[image]

How can I make this data into the following format?

```
dstrSpecificHelpRs: {
    {name: "", value: ""},
    {name: "", value: ""}
    {name: "", value: ""}
    ...
  },
  rgstInfoRs: {
    {name: "", value: ""},
    {name: "", value: ""}
    {name: "", value: ""}
    ...
  }
```

This is what I currently have:

```
getObject(action) {
  let returnOptions=[];
  Object.keys(action.payload).forEach(key => {
    const payload = action.payload[key];
    _.map(payload, (data) => {
      _.filter(data['row'], (item) => {
        returnOptions.push({
          [key]: {
            name: item.name,
            value: item.value
          }
        })
      })
    })
  })
  return returnOptions;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the one what you are looking for. 
Use below code :

```js
const data = [
    {
        dstrSpecificHelpRs: {
            name: "name 1",
            value: "value 1"
        }
    },
    {
        dstrSpecificHelpRs: {
            name: "name 2",
            value: "value 2"
        }
    },
    {
        rgstInfoRs: {
            name: "info name 1",
            value: "info value 1"
        }
    },
    {
        rgstInfoRs: {
            name: "info name 2",
            value: "info value 2"
        }
    },
    {
        dstrSpecificHelpRs: {
            name: "name 3",
            value: "value 3"
        }
    }
]
let newData = {}
data.forEach((value) => {
    Object.keys(value).forEach((key) => {
        if(newData[key] === undefined){
            newData[key] = [value[key]]
        } else {
            newData[key].push(value[key])
        }
    })
});
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Let me know if this helps.

```js
const data = [
 {dstrSpecificHelpRs: { name: 'a', value: 'b' } },
 {dstrSpecificHelpRs: { name: 'c', value: 'd' } },
 {dstrSpecificHelpRs: { name: 'e', value: 'f' } },
 {dstrSpecificHelpRs: { name: 'g', value: 'h' } },
 {rgstInfoRs: { name: 'i', value: 'j' } },
 {rgstInfoRs: { name: 'k', value: 'l' } },
 {rgstInfoRs: { name: 'm', value: 'n' } },
 {rgstInfoRs: { name: 'o', value: 'p' } },
]

function getObject(action) {
    const dstrSpecificHelpRs = [];
    const rgstInfoRs = [];

    action.payload.forEach((item) => {
      if (item['dstrSpecificHelpRs']) {
          dstrSpecificHelpRs.push(item);
      }

      if (item['rgstInfoRs']) {
          rgstInfoRs.push(item);
      }
    });

    return { dstrSpecificHelpRs, rgstInfoRs };
}

console.log(getObject({ payload: data }));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but this didn't work out.